# Proving the limit is equal even if approached along some function.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to prove the following:

> Let $f$ be a real valued function of n variables.
> Suppose that $$\lim_{X\to X_0}f(X)=L,$$
> where $X_0=(x_{01},x_{02},...,x_{0n})\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose also that there are functions $h_k(x)$ such that,
> $$\lim_{x\to x_{01}}h_k(x)=x_{0k},\hspace{2mm} 1\leq k \leq n.$$
> Then,
> $$\lim_{x\to x_{01}}g(x)=L,$$
> where $g(x)=f(\tilde{X}), \hspace{2mm} \tilde{X}=(h_1(x),h_2(x),...,h_n(x)).$

For the most part the proof is quite straight forward. I am however stuck on a detail in the very end and I'm not sure if it because I can't come up with the right idea or that the conditions given are not sufficient. This is my attempt so far:

If $\varepsilon>0$ is given, then since the first limit exists we can find some $\delta$ such that if $|X-X_0|<\delta$ and $X\in D_f$ then $|f(X)-L|<\varepsilon$.

Because of the existance of these functions $h_k$ and their limit at $x_{01},$ we can find some $\tilde{\delta}$ such that if $|x-x_{01}|<\tilde{\delta}$ then $|h_k(x)-x_{0k}|<\frac{\delta}{\sqrt{n}}, \hspace{2mm} 1\leq k \leq n$

Which would imply that $|\tilde{X}-X_0|<\delta$

This is where I'm stuck. How can I show that there are always points $x\in (x_{01}-\delta,x_{01}+\delta)$ such that $\tilde{X}\in D_f$? Which is needed to prove the result. Am I missing some idea or do I need to add more conditions to the functions $h_k$?

Comment: Is $D_f$ in your proposed solution the domain of the function $f$? Or what? If the former (suggesting that $f$ is not necessarily defined in a neighbourhood of $X_0$), then you probably need some more conditions on $g$ to make the conjecture valid.

Comment: Yes, it is the domain of $f$.

Comment: Now that you say it, just $f$ being defined on some deleted neighbourhood of $X_0$ should be enough since we could choose $x$ close enough to $x_{01}$ such that $\tilde{X}$ is in that neighbourhood, right?

Comment: Yes, if it is implicit that $f$ is defined on a punctured neighbourhood of $X_0$ then all should be well. I think you can probably answer the question for yourself now.

Comment: If $f$ has a removable discontinuity at $X_0$ and the curve $\tilde X$ goes through $X_0$ infinitely often as $x \to x_{01}$, then the result is false.  (For example, think of the case where $\tilde X(x) = (x\sin (1/x), 0, \ldots, 0)$ and $x_{01} = 0$, $X_0 = 0$.)  So, you need an assumption either that $f$ is continuous at $X_0$, or that there is some $\delta_0 > 0$ such that $0 < |x - x_{01}| < \delta_0$ implies $\tilde X(x) \ne X_0$.

Comment: Thought about it for a while, and now I see your point. Great addition!